# Why is Django connection.cursor query failing?

Tags: django, django-models

I am getting the following error message when trying to execute a cursor query against a SQLite3 database:
[image]

My code is as follows:

```
    qry = ('select balancer_security.id, balancer_security.name, balancer_security.symbol, '
           'balancer_securityprice.at_dt, balancer_securityprice.price, balancer_securityprice.notes '
           'from balancer_security LEFT OUTER JOIN balancer_securityprice '
           'ON (balancer_security.id = balancer_securityprice.security_id '
           'AND balancer_securityprice.at_dt="?") '
           # 'AND balancer_securityprice.at_dt="%s") '
           'ORDER BY balancer_security.name')
    from django.db import connection
    cursor = connection.cursor()
    cursor.execute(qry, [date])
    solution = cursor.fetchall()
```

The error occurs on the cursor.execute line. *date* is a string containing the value *2017-10-05*

Also, is the parameter put into the query within django or is it passed to SQLite (i.e. should my parameter placeholder be %s or ?)?

Thanks!

Comment: `%s` should solve your problem. Have you tried it?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but %s results in the following error: ProgrammingError at /balancer/set_security_prices/2017-10-05
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 0, and there are 1 supplied.

Comment: Are you doing this `"%s"` or this `%s`. Use it without quotes

Comment: @JahongirRahmonov You, Sir, are a genius!!! Your solution worked. Thank you so much - I've been fighting this for two days now. If you log your solution as an 'answer' I can mark it as the correct solution. Thanks again!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just use it without quotes. Change `"%s"` to just `%s`.